# interpolate into string in java

Tags: java, interpolation

Say I have a list of char variables called perm1, perm2, perm3, ..., perm10.

I am doing the same function to all ten char variables, and would rather put them through a loop using something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i ++){
    doSomething(perm$i);
}
```

What would be the correct syntax for this idea, similar I guess to interpolation in Perl?

Thank you!!

Comment: I suggest that you use an array rather than 10 separate variables.

Comment: In Java, it's not idiomatic to use similarly named fields to store groups of items.  Use a single field with an array.  You could use reflection, but that would be considered an abuse of the language by most code reviewers/maintainers.

Comment: Such interpolation doesn't exist in Java, and is a bad idea in Perl as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you need interpolate the variables into a string, use the [format method of String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

```
String[] perms = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" };  
String result = String.format("perm1=%s perm2=%s ... perm10=%s;", (Object[])perms );
```

Answer (score 0):

Stuff them in an array and loop over the array.